# How to specify Youtube Channel Id to Upload Video from the same user?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using this code to upload to my Youtube Channel that is working fine. Now I created another channel under my account and I want to upload a video to this new Chanel, how do I specify the channel Id in the code?

```
# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1

# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10

# Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError)

# Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
# codes is raised.
RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "youtube_client_secret.json"
# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
# authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0
To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:
   %s
with information from the API Console
https://console.developers.google.com/
For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES = ("public", "private", "unlisted")


def get_authenticated_service(args):
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
                                   scope=YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE,
                                   message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

    storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
    credentials = storage.get()

    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

    return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
                 http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))


def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
    tags = None
#   if options.keywords:
#     tags = options.keywords.split(",")

    body = dict(
        snippet=dict(
            title=options['title'],
            description=options['description'],
            tags=tags,
            # categoryId=options['category']
        ),
        status=dict(
            privacyStatus=options['privacyStatus']
        )
    )

    # Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
        part=",".join(body.keys()),
        body=body,
        media_body=MediaFileUpload(
            options['file'], chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
    )

    resumable_upload(insert_request)

# This method implements an exponential backoff strategy to resume a
# failed upload.


def resumable_upload(insert_request):
    response = None
    error = None
    retry = 0
    while response is None:
        try:
            print("Uploading file...")
            status, response = insert_request.next_chunk()
            if response is not None:
                if 'id' in response:
                    print("Video id '%s' was successfully uploaded." %
                          response['id'])
                else:
                    exit("The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s" % response)
        except HttpError as e:
            if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
                error = "A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status,
                                                                     e.content)
            else:
                raise
        except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS as e:
            error = "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e

        if error is not None:
            print(error)
            retry += 1
            if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
                exit("No longer attempting to retry.")

            max_sleep = 2 ** retry
            sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
            print("Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying..." % sleep_seconds)
            time.sleep(sleep_seconds)


def upload_video(video_data):
    args = argparser.parse_args()
    if not os.path.exists(video_data['file']):
        exit("Please specify a valid file using the --file= parameter.")

    youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
    try:
        initialize_upload(youtube, video_data)
    except HttpError as e:
        print("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube authorization is channel based not user based.   When you ran your code you picked a channel you with the user credentials you have you can upload to only that channel.

you need to authorize your code again this is normally done by removing the token.json file or the token.pickle in python which is used to store the user credentials unfortunately I can't see that in your code maybe `storage`